# why not pulling data for last week

Tags: mysql

Why wouldn't this be working for pulling data from last week?

```
if($_GET['reminder'] == 'lastweek') {
$lastweek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last sunday'));
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND contacttodo.reminder BETWEEN '$lastweek' AND '$lastweek' - INTERVAL 6 DAY ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of BETWEEN:

```
expr BETWEEN min AND max
```

so you should put the smaller value (minimum) first:

```
BETWEEN '$lastweek' - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND '$lastweek'
```

`'$lastweek' - INTERVAL 6 DAY ORDER` is smaller than `'$lastweek'`